# VC++ Can't Manipulate Forms

Tags: multithreading, forms

I've just started a new VC++ Form project. I understand that I can manipulate my forms through events on the generated form header file.

However, for better design, I want to be able to update the form from external controlling objects (for instance when new data is generated in the system at large).

The problem is, in the generated main file, Application::Run( gcnew () ); means that I can't send any commands through (e.g. changing text on a button) because this is constantly running until the form is closed.

How do you typically deal with this? Am I approaching this in the wrong manner?

Many Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Well, that's just autogenerated code.  You don't *have* to use it, you can change it.  So you can pass the object reference you need to other classes.  Works well from the main form constructor to.  It is *this*.